# nohup service inside docker container

Tags: laravel, docker

I have trouble disowning process inside docker container:

```
sudo docker exec -it php7-fpm bash -c 'nohup php /www/site/artisan queue:listen >> /www/site/nohup.log 2>&1'
```

Service works fine until I ctrl+c. Is there any way I can disown this process without killing it?

Comment: If all you care about is that process running forever just use `&` at the end of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip all the effort to nohup and background, instead just detach from the process (note the `-d`):

```
sudo docker exec -itd php7-fpm bash -c 'php /www/site/artisan queue:listen'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do this.  "docker exec" is intended as a debugging convenience. It's not intended to be used to run real services.

The intention is that services are run with "docker run", using an image defined by a Dockerfile, producing a single container.  That image can run multiple processes, as long as they are very tightly coupled to each other.  If not, you should use multiple containers.

You can have variances in what's running in each container by varying the command you run on the "docker run" command line.

Alternatively, to connect coupled containers, you can use "docker compose" to define each of the related services and their relationship to each other.

Comment: What is an alternative?